iOS project reports error of provisioning profile not including the current mac os computer
I'm trying to move jenkins building jobs of our Unity3D project to a new mac machine with apple M2 chipset. Things go well before the xcode part. I copy the certificates (p12) and the corresponding provisioning profiles and install them on the new machine, and I run the following command (as we did before) for the xcode archiving stage.
xcodebuild archive -workspace Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace -scheme Unity-iPhone -configuration Release -archivePath XXXXXX CODE_SIGN_STYPE=MANUAL CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Developer" PROVISIONING_PROFILE_APP=xxxxxx PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER_APP=XXXXXX

Errors show for both the provisioning profile saying that
Provisioning profile xxxxxx doesn't include the currently selected device "MyMacMachineName" (identifier xxxxxx). (in target 'Unity-iPhone' from project 'Unity-iPhone')

Weird thing here is that the selected device is my mac rather than any iOS device (I'm not connecting any).
This problem ONLY occurs in COMMAND LINE. Xcode 15.4, Mac OS 14.3
Any clue?

As the error says, you need to ensure that the device is included in the provisioning profile. If you have already done that, try to refresh profiles manually.
However, if you create an ios-target build, it is strange that the system asks you to add your computer.

This is exactly why I'm asking this question here. I'm doing ios-target build only. Besides, when I open xcode and click 'Build' in the menu things go well!

If the issue is command-line only, and all works fine manually, it needs to be mentioned in the question. Versions of mac os and xcode can also be helpful. Perhaps, it is something related to beta versions.

Got it, I'll edit the question

Sounds like you want to build an iOS app, but your build process also builds for macOS and you can’t build for your build machine.

When we use old mac machines, things got right. But with the Apple chipset machine, we need to explicitly add the following to the xcodebuild CLI tool:
-destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -destination 'generic/platform=iPadOS'

